# How to load an image in a specific spot

Tags: javascript, html, image

I am trying to achieve this:
When someone uploads an image, the image uploads in one of the smaller boxes on the right and when they upload another image clicking on the big box, this image is uploaded on the other right small box. Please see the image attached. Can this be achieved using Javascript and HTML?[Image representing the query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTvNB.png)

```html
Here is my html:
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
              <img src="box.jpg">
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
              <img src="smallBox.jpg" id="smallimg1">
              <img src="smallBox.jpg" id="smallimg">
              <img src="smallBox.jpg" id="smallimg">
              <img src="smallBox.jpg" id="smallimg">
              <img src="smallBox.jpg" id="smallimg">
              <img src="smallBox.jpg" id="smallimg">
              <img src="smallBox.jpg" id="smallimg">
              <img src="smallBox.jpg" class="img-responsive">
              <img src="smallBox.jpg" id="smallimg1">
                <div style="margin-top:12px;">
                <img src="smallBox.jpg" id="smallimg1">
                <img src="smallBox.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                <img src="smallBox.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                <img src="smallBox.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                <img src="smallBox.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                <img src="smallBox.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                <img src="smallBox.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                <img src="smallBox.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                <img src="smallBox.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                <img src="transparentBox.png" style="border:1px dashed black;" id="imgdotted">
                <div id="darkBox"><img src="smallDarkBox.jpg" style="position: absolute;z-index: 2;left: 380px;top: 35px;"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: can do, but what have you tried.

Comment: Actually im not that good in JS. Can you please help me out?

Comment: I would suggest find a good uploader lib like http://www.dropzonejs.com/, would make it really simple.

Comment: Is there code you can help me wityh. I guess first i need to store in a variable the image uploaded and that variable can be an array and then upload the image on the box on the right but not quite sure how to upload the image on the right using JS.

Answer (score 0):

So to clarify, you want to upload images and they fill up those small boxes as you add them? Not sure of what you have currently, but if that snippet is all you have then you have a lot of work ahead of you. There are 100 different ways to achieve this task, here are a few suggestions:

You will need a mechanism for uploading images. Some sort of server side programming, such as .NET, PHP or some other kind of API. If you are trying to use javascript, then you will need an API. The JS in the browser will post that image to the api. The code in the api will read the api request and save the file online somewhere. An alternative could be a web form that accepts a file and "submits" the form, which is essentially an api post and will still require server side code, but its a simpler approach than manually calling the api with js. That will fulfill the task of getting an image from a user's browser to a server where the image is stored.

Once uploaded, the web page needs to know about and download all the stored images. This will require either another server side call (API call, .NET web app, etc) to fetch the contents, either from a database (complex) or just scanning through the web folder they are stored on (simple). You could probably query a web folder using only javascript client side and avoid another server call if need be. You will need to update the image tag's src attribute with the location of the images

All this is far easier said than done, and sorry if I didn't get in to too much detail but there is a lot to cover. I'm really just trying to point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Yes, that looks so much!